# Checking for independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Jane  bought  an  item  from  Lenny  over  Craigslist.  They  want  to  meet  at the train  station. Since they are both working part-time with irregular working hours they agree on the following:
If JAne arrives at a random, uniformely distributed minute between 12 and 1 pm and waits for 15 minutes.
If Lenny doesn't show up in that time span, she will head home. Lenny follows the same strategy.
COnsider the meeting of Jane and Lenny and observe the following events:

•T : They meet

•E: Jane arrives after 12:30

•F: Jane arrives after 12:30 and Lenny arrives before 12:30.

Check the three pairs ( T;E ) ; ( T;F ) and ( E;F ) for independence.

So I started it with $$P(T)=7/16$$
$$P(E)=1/2$$
$$P(F)=1/4$$
SO then for (T, E)= (7/16)*(1/2)

(T, F)= (7/16)*(1/4)

(E, F)= (1/2)*(1/4)

So then they ARE independent right? Or am I wrong?

Comment: for independence you have to prove $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$

Answer (score 1):

To determine whether two events are independent you need to calculate the probability that both events occur, and then compare it with the product of their individual probabilities.

For example:

$P(T \cap E) = \frac{7}{32}$

$P(T) \times P(E) = \frac{7}{16} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{7}{32}$

So $P(T \cap E) = P(T) \times P(E)$ which shows that T and E are independent.

However, it is fairly clear that E and F are *not* independent, because F can only occur if E also occurs. So we have

$P(E \cap F) = \frac{1}{4}$

$P(E) \times P(F) = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{8}$

So $P(E \cap F) \ne P(E) \times P(F)$ which shows that E and E are not independent.

Comment: How did you get $$P(E∩F)=1/4$$ ?

Comment: $P(\text{Jane arrives after 12:30} \cap \text{Jane arrives after 12:30 and Lenny arrives before 12:30}) = P(\text{Jane arrives after 12:30 and Lenny arrives before 12:30}) = \frac{1}{4}$

Comment: Did you do it by 900/3600?